# modify keys in JSON.stringify()

Tags: json, flash, actionscript

I am looking to do a `JSON.stringify` on an `ActionScript` object, while at the same time encoding the json string.

For instance, say I have something which encodes to

```
{"name":"Jimmy Page","band":"LEDZEP"}
```

I would want it to be encoded as

```
{"~N~":"Jimmy Page","~B~":"LEDZEP"}
```

instead. How do I achieve something like this, keep in mind that the actual objects would be quite nested. Could I use `JSON.stringify` with the `replacer parameter` somehow? I have been able to modify the value, but I would like to replace the key instead. Any pointers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can by add the [DataMember] Attribute on the field, then add the datamember name like this:
    ...
    [DataMember(Name="N")]
    public string FirstName{get; set;}
    ...

Comment: I don't quite follow, can you show me an example code? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, am wrong in the last answer i think you work with .net, okay you can use a replacer function readm more about it at:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html